# RequiredMessage don't show in p:messages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to display a requiredMessage in p:messages but dont works. The p:messages just show the messages from BackingBean using addMessage().

See:

```
<p:messages globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" />
<h:form id="frmRegistro">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <h:inputText value="#{usuarioLogadoMB.newUser.nomeCompleto}"
                        styleClass="form-control" alt="Nome Completo"
                        pt:placeholder="Nome completo" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <h:inputText value="#{usuarioLogadoMB.newUser.email}" id="iptEmail"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="O email é obrigatório"
                        styleClass="form-control" alt="Email" pt:placeholder="Email" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <h:inputSecret value="#{usuarioLogadoMB.newUser.senha}"
                        required="true" requiredMessage="A senha é obrigatória"
                        styleClass="form-control" alt="Senha" pt:placeholder="Senha" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <h:inputSecret value="#{usuarioLogadoMB.newUser.confirmacaoSenha}"
                        required="true"
                        requiredMessage="A confirmação da senha é obrigatória"
                        styleClass="form-control" alt="Repita a senha"
                        pt:placeholder="Repita a senha" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h:commandButton action="#{usuarioLogadoMB.concluirRegistro()}"
                            value="Registrar" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
            </h:form>
```

If i put p:message with for attribute to each component the message is showed inline, but i want to use the p:messages to avoid add p:message to each component.

Comment: `requiredMessage` is specified for a component which it belongs to, so `p:messages` with attribute `globalOnly="true"` won't pick it up. Try removing this attribute.

Comment: If i use globalOnly="false" to general cases and need use p:message to a specific component this may not cause problem ?

Comment: If you have `p:messages globalOnly="false"` and `p:message for="someInputId"` then you can have duplicated error messages because `p:messages` will display everything. You can just try and check it out yourself.

Comment: exactly, the message is duplicated. So, i can't use globalONly="true" because i need show requiredMEssage, and i can't use globalONly="false" because message is duplicated for specific components. How can i solve this

Comment: And this does not happen with h:messages

Comment: thanks for everyone, i'll use p:messages anyway.